# Activation function for multiclass multilabel data

Tags: keras, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I am making a simple image multilabel multiclass image classification. In this image is divided into 6 class and each class in 3 sub category (1, 2, 3).
I made a simple model with **sigmoid**  Activation and used **binary cross_entropy**.
Here is my code :

```html
  model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))
  return model

  model.compile(optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.003, decay=1e-6),loss="binary_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I should use **softmax** for getting result into 3 sub categories but I don't know how should I use it.

Answer (score 1):

break down your problem in multiple tasks and make a model for each task and ensemble it together.

if you have a multilabel task use **sigmoid activation** in the last layer and use **softmax activation** when you have a multi-classification problem.

For ensembling multiple models together you can use [tf.cond](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) or [tf.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) to use a particular model according to the prediction of the first base model.

Comment: How about one hot encoding?

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand what are you asking, I am suggesting to train individual models for each task.